# Azure Static Web App unable to connect to Supabase

Tags: node.js, azure, nuxt.js, supabase, azure-static-web-app

So, I have a static web app hosted on Azure (learning purposes), and the same app hosted on Vercel. Both of them point to the same Supabase project.

I have had in the past issues with Vercel caching prisma artifacts and Azure actually displaying the content from the PostGres DB. Now, I have deployed (changing my scripts to generate) and the issue appears to have switched, although now when I try to login on my Azure app, I get:

```
AuthRetryableFetchError: URL is not valid or contains user credentials.
```

This has all started after I updated a yml file (which fixed an Azure deployment issue), but then I had an apparent issue with the supabase variables I was useing on Azure. The Vercel app was loading content from supabase, but Azure doesn't. So, I deleted the variables on Azure, and re-entered them  and now I have reached the error above.

I believe the error to be in Azure, although I am not 100% sure yet, but I'm struggling now ...

What I've tried:

- ChatGPT
- Redeploying the yml
- Updating the Azure web app token
- Removing Azure env variables and re-entering
- Tested the same variables on the Vercel app
- Tested the same branch, with the same env vars and some supabase project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error message `AuthRetryableFetchError: URL is not valid or contains user credentials` shows that there is an issue with the URL or the user credentials.

1. Check the Supabase credentials and [CORS Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services).
2. Verify the environment variables in Azure portal and check whether they are mapped correctly and match with the Supabase credentials.

[image]

3. Check the Azure deployment logs for any errors or warnings related to Supabase connectivity.
4. Check the Azure AD authentication and authorization logs.

[image]

5. Check the Gateway logs and activity logs for any issues.

[image]

Use the below query (query reference from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway)) to check the application Gateway logs.

```
AzureDiagnostics  
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess" and httpStatus_d > 399  
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), _ResourceId  
| render timechart
```

[image]

For more information, check this [blog.](https://docs.draftbit.com/docs/supabase)

Comment: Thank you for this! I ended up deleting the Supabase project (as it’s in its infancy), however I didn’t like not knowing the correct fix. So thanks for the insight, at least I can look in to this now for future reference 